# re2 - different behavior between Match/PartialMatch/FindAndConsume

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I'm using re2 library to find regex matches in a text. I can see that there is a difference in behavior between `Match()/PartialMatch()/FindAndConsume()` - in the following code only `Match()` returns true and fills the submatch string.

If I change the regex to capturing group, i.e. `(\\d+)` instead of `\\d+`, then all three functions succeed and fill the submatch.

I couldn't find any documentation of this behavior in re2 headers. can someone please explain why `PartialMatch()/FindAndConsume()` require capturing group and why `Match()` doesn't?

```
    std::string text = "b123";
    re2::StringPiece sp(text);
    RE2 regex("\\d+");

    re2::StringPiece submatch;
    bool ret = regex.Match(sp, 0, text.size(), RE2::UNANCHORED, &submatch, 1); //returns true and fills submatch

    ret = RE2::PartialMatch(sp, regex, &submatch); //fails

    while (RE2::FindAndConsume(&sp, regex, &submatch)) { //fails
        std::cout << submatch << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments in the re2 headers for `PartialMatch` and `FindAndConsume` state that they `return true iff ... b. The number of matched sub-patterns is >= number of supplied pointers.`

Your code supplies one pointer `&submatch`.  Your regex `\d+` has no sub-patterns and thus always fails.  The regex `(\d+)` has one sub-pattern and thus can succeed with your input text.

`PartialMatch()` and `FindAndConsume()` do not provide a way to retrieve the overall regex match without wrapping the whole regex in a capturing group.

`Match()` does fill `submatch[0]` with the overall regex match if you pass `nsubmatch >= 1`.  If fills `submatch[1]..submatch[NumberOfCapturingGroups()]` with the matches of the sub-patterns if you pass `nsubmatch >= 1 + NumberOfCapturingGroups()`.  The header comment for `Match()` does not explicitly state that it fills `submatch[0]` with the overall regex match.  But it can be inferred from the example and from the fact that it suggests that `1 + NumberOfCapturingGroups()` is the largest sensible value for `nsubmatch`.